# I am not sure if this video card is AGP 8x or 4x

Tags: agp

[image]

I hope you can help confirm if it is an AGP 8x or AGP 4x.
I am lookingfor an adapter for it such that it can be reused.

Comment: The question is fine; the answer is correct... but I still have to ask... could you not simply get a faster, more energy efficient new card for 20 bucks/quid/euros i.e., probably less than a specialist converter?

Comment: The GeForce GT 710, 720, 730 etc. series are very cheap and performance will be at least double or triple. I'm not sure on the price, but i Denmark alone the cheapest one is about $35, so i suspect it'll be a lot cheaper in the US/UK.

Comment: @Tetsujin, you are right.

Comment: @DavidWashington - I just didn't want you unnecessarily spending money unless the card would be serving some specialist purpose :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your card is AGP x2/x4. it is seen by the 3 separating spaces. 
[image]